# Erro no FIREBASE + NODEJS: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists

Tags: node.js, firebase, express.js

Tenho um CRUD feito com NODEJS + EXPRESS, utilizando o FIREBASE.

Adiciono um registro normalmente, mas, quando vou adicionar o próximo, ele me dá o erro:

[DEFAULT]: Firebase: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).

Se eu restartar o servidor, funciona. Pelo que vi, estou acionando a conexão múltiplas vezes, mas não sei onde corrigir isso.

Podem me explicar?

```
var fb = this._firebase.database();

var result = fb.ref().child('clientes/').orderByChild('empresa').equalTo(cliente.cnpj);
result.once('value').then(function(snapshot){

    var erros;
    if(snapshot.length < 0){
        erros = { 
            erro: 'CNPJ já cadastrado.'
        };
        return erros;
    }

    var key = fb.ref('clientes/').push(cliente).key;

    var mensagem = {
        msg: 'Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!',
        status: 'success'
    }

    res.render('clientes/clientes', { validacao: {}, dadosForm: {}, mensagem: mensagem });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre normalmente quando a função

`firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)`

é chamada mais de uma vez. Verifique onde está ocorrendo está chamada, se ela não está em um loop ou se ela está sendo chamada sempre que uma nova requisição é feita.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro ocorre quando voce chama `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` mais que uma vez.

Para corrigir isto basta fazer o seguinte:

```
if(!firebase.apps.length){
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
}
```

Dessa forma ele verificará se ja existe algum app inicializado e caso exista não entrará no if.

OBS: Você pode modificar o if para `firebase.apps.length < 1` ou algo semelhante a isso, usei a negação pois o JS reconhece `0` como `false`

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Este erro ocorre quando voce chama `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` mais que uma vez, por isso o ideal é criar um nome para cada app.

Essa é a função iniciar app que recebe dois parametros:

```
function initializeApp(options: Object, name?: string): firebase.app.App;
```

Passe o nome que deve ser uma string no segundo paramentro :

```
const options : Object = {
    apiKey: "apiKey",
    authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
  };

const app = firebase.initializeApp(options, "name");
```

Answer (score -1):

In web version 9 you can use:

```
import { initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID
}

// Initialize Firebase
export const app =
  getApps().length > 0 ? getApps()[0] : initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```